# Mocking ViewModels for ui testing in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I'm currently building a jetpack compose app with Kotlin and I experience difficulties with testing the navigation of the app.

I want to mock my ViewModels so my tests are not dependend of the api and so on. I have tried different things for mocking the viewmodels but none of them worked. I have found out that the way to go is by mocking the factory, but I can't figure out how to do it.

For the initialization of the vm's I have the following factory:

```
object AppViewModelProvider {
    val Factory = viewModelFactory {

        initializer {
            FavoriteViewModel(fieldFavoritesApplication().container.favoriteRepository)
        }
    //More initializers...
    }
}

fun CreationExtras.fieldFavoritesApplication(): FieldFavoritesApplication =
    (this[AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY] as FieldFavoritesApplication)
```

Here is the function signature of the navigation host:

```
fun FieldFavoritesNavHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    favoriteViewModel: FavoriteViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
)
```

And finally the test itself:

```
class NavigationTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()
    lateinit var navController:TestNavHostController

    @Before
    fun setupAppNavHost() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            navController = TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current)
            navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(ComposeNavigator())
            FieldFavoritesApp(navController)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun verifyStartDestination()  {
        Assert.assertEquals(LeaguesDestination.route, navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route)
    }
}
```

How can I mock the factory so I can use fake viewmodels in this test?

Comment: Are these APIs used directly in the `ViewModel`s or through injected repositories etc.? Also do you use a dependency injection framework?

Comment: @JanItor I took my structure from this repo: https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app/tree/main
I don't use any di framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mock a `ViewModel` in a project structured similarly to [Inventory app](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app/tree/main) you can create `ViewModel` file with the same file name and location in the `androidTest` source set. For example, if you have `FavoriteViewModel` in `ui.favorites` package in your app, create `ui.favorites` package in `androidTest` and put mock `FavoriteViewModel` implementation there, it will be used instead of the original one.

Alternatively, you can keep the original `ViewModel`s but mock repositories instead in a similar way. For example, if you want to mock `ItemsRepository` in [Inventory app](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app/tree/main), create `TestItemsRepository` implementing `ItemsRepository` in the `androidTest`. Then create `AppContainer` in `data` package that will provide your test implementation:

```
override val itemsRepository: ItemsRepository by lazy {
    TestItemsRepository()
}
```